# Error on tagit plugin usage: "TypeError: $(...).tagit is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, tag-it

When using in html:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#question-meta").tagit({
            fieldName: "meta"
        });
    });
    </script>
<ul id="question-meta"></ul>
```

I use it according to instructions:
https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it
(all js/css files are included as written there)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow. When asking questions like this, a good way to get answers is to post whatever you have till now. That way it becomes easier to understand the question and point out suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Include this libraries in head tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/aehlke/tag-it/master/js/tag-it.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/css/jquery.tagit.css">
```